# permutations of identical elements: efficiently avoid redundant permutations

Tags: python, python-itertools

*My problem:*

I have, e.g., 4 numbers

```
a, b, c, d = np.random.rand(4)
```

and I need all of the possible sums `a + b - c`, `a + b -d`, `b + c - d`, `b + c -a` etc etc

I have found that I can proceed like this

```
from itertools import permutations

p = np.array(list(set(permutations([1, 1, -1, 0])))).T
sums = np.random.rand(4) @ p
```

and so far so good, I've vectorized my problem... what hurts my feelings is the use of `permutations(…)` because the number of permutations, for `n` numbers to combine, is of course `n!` while the filter operated by `set` reduces the number of the significant permutations to a few percent.

*My question:*

Is it possible to obtain, e.g.,

```
p = np.array(list(set(permutations([1]*5 + [-1]*4 + [0]*6)))).T
```

without computing all the 1,307,674,368,000 (mostly identical) permutations?

---

Following the advice of [Lukas Thaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10293548/lukas-thaler) and of [Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) I have checked the possible use of `sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations`

```
In [1]: from itertools import permutations                                                

In [2]: from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset, multiset_permutations             

In [3]: for n in (2,3): 
   ...:     l = [1]*n +[2]*n + [3]*n 
   ...:     ms = multiset(l) 
   ...:     print(n*3) 
   ...:     %timeit list(multiset_permutations(ms)) 
   ...:     %timeit set(permutations(l)) 
   ...:                                                                                   
6
568 µs ± 3.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
91.3 µs ± 571 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
9
9.32 ms ± 209 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
58.3 ms ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It seems to me that

1. for negligible amounts of computation it doesn't matter anyway
2. when the things stiffen, the pure Python implementation in Sympy easily overcomes the brute force approach using `set` and `itertools.permutations`

so that I conclude that my question is a duplicate of the question referenced by Chris and I vote to close it.

Comment: this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895696/prevent-duplicates-from-itertool-permutation

Comment: @Chris_Rands Re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895696/prevent-duplicates-from-itertool-permutation accepted answer suggest to use `set` to filter `permutations` results, so I don't need that answer (that technique is already used in my question).  I'll look at the other question you suggested, it looks more promising but at the moment I'm not sure it is a duplicate (the OP has an edit in which they say the problem is about `itertools.product` and that is not my case).

Comment: Here's a classic permutation algorithm which handles duplicated items correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31678111/4014959 My code in that answer is for strings, but it should be easy to adapt it for your purposes.

Comment: [sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations) seems to solve your problem

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you, I'll look into it.  I was hoping for a C speed solution but it's likely that a better algorithm wins hands down for _n!_ sufficiently large. I'll update with some stats as soon as I have some time to benchmark.

Comment: @LukasThaler Thank you Lukas, the `multiset_permutations` is cited in an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values, reported by Chris Rands. I fear that it's a pure Python implementation, again it's a matter of benchmarking when algorithm beats brute force...

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by first using `combinations` to pick the numbers used in the summation and then using it again to pick the positive (and negative) numbers.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from random import random

def our_sums_of(nums, num_positive):
    return (2 * sum(positives) - sum(nums) 
            for positives in combinations(nums, num_positive))

nums = [random() for _ in range(15)]
num_positive = 5
num_negative = 4

list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda c: our_sums_of(c, num_positive), 
                             combinations(nums, num_positive + num_negative))))
```

Comment: OP has 4 numbers in their post though, and they may be looking for a program which can handle any amount of numbers.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I see that now.  I've adjusted my answer to handle that more general situation.

Comment: Kyle, as far as I can tell you provided a smart way to compute the sums, but if you read carefully my question you should recognize that **I'm interested in an efficient way of computing `p`**, so no, I'm sorry but your answer is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity can be much lower using `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

z = 6 # number of zeros
p = 5 # number of 1s
n = 4 # number of -1s

indexes = set(range(z+p+n))

res = np.array([(*plus, *minus, *(zero for zero in indexes - set(plus) - set(minus)))
                for plus in combinations(indexes, p)
                for minus in combinations(indexes-set(plus), n)])

perm = np.zeros((res.shape[0], z+p+n), dtype=np.int8)
perm[np.arange(res[:,:p].shape[0])[:,None], res[:,:p]] = 1
perm[np.arange(res[:,p:p+n].shape[0])[:,None], res[:,p:p+n]] = -1
```

Basically, instead of computing all the permutations (complexity `(n+p+z)!`), I first select the positive elements (complexity `(n+p+z)!/(p!(n+z)!)`) and then select the negative ones (complexity `(n+z)!/(n!z!)`). The resulting complexity should be something like `(n+p+z)!/(n!p!z!)`

Comment: Riccardo, my fault but I do not see how I should apply your method to my problem.  Could you please apply it to, e.g., `[-1]*2+[0]*3+[1]*2` ?

Comment: @gboffi I made an example. Check if it works for you. I can also explain you why this is faster than your approach

Comment: I'll repeat myself: probably my fault but I do not see how I should apply your method to my problem.

Comment: @gboffi You need to compute all the sums in an efficient way, don't you? Well, this is what my algorithm does. What is not clear?

Comment: _My question:_ is it possible to obtain, e.g.,  `p = …`  without computing all the 1,307,674,368,000 (mostly identical) permutations? IOW, I'm interested in `p` and not in the sums — you are correct that possibly we have better ways of computing the sums **but I'm interested in `p`**

Comment: @gboffi Ok, I fivex the answer to find what you have asked for. It's still performing better than your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204532/discussion-between-riccardo-bucco-and-gboffi).