# List comprehension of a permutation

Tags: python, list-comprehension, permutation

I'm trying to create a list from a permutation of a str object. However the resultant list has duplicates. I have the following code:

```
from itertools import permutations
a = permutations('144')
b = [''.join(i) for i in a]
print(b)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting the following:

```
['144', '144', '414', '441', '414', '441']
```

Comment: Because your original elements have duplicates (two 4s)

Comment: Easiest way to handle this may be to convert it to a `set` if the idea is that the str can have repeated characters.

Comment: I would answer, but I think the answer is well documented here, although if your output is small, using set on the list to eliminate duplicates isn't a bad idea for simplicity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895696/prevent-duplicates-from-itertools-permutations With this I think it's safe to say this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

No. That is the expected result because there are duplicate characters in your input string.

If all you are interested are the elements of the permutation then pass your list through `set`. If instead you NEED a list, pass it through `list` again

Example:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = permutations('144')
b = set(''.join(i) for i in a) 
c = list(set(''.join(i) for i in a)) # note that I've removed square brackets
print(b)
print(c)
```

Protip: use generator expressions wherever possible

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate elements (characters) in your string. The function `permutations` will not distinguish between them.

You will have no duplicates if you iterate the permutations of the set of the characters, e.g.:

```
from itertools import permutations
a = permutations(set('144'))
b = [''.join(i) for i in a]
print(b)
```

Or, if you want to iterate over the disctinct permutations of the string containing even duplicates of the same characters, you can use the `set` of the permutations, like:

```
from itertools import permutations
a = permutations('144')
b = [''.join(i) for i in set(a)]
print(b)
```

Comment: `a=itertools.combinations_with_replacement(set("144"), 3)`    incase the output has to be of three elements. `['444', '441', '411', '111']`

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is asking, using set on the characters makes the output [14, 41] instead of ['144', '414', '441'].

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the answer to include a solution for the other target as well.